# React radio button selecting only the previous click

Tags: javascript, reactjs

**Homepage.jsx**

```
const Homepage = () => {
    const [categories, setCategories] = useState([])
    const [products, setProducts] = useState([])
    const [selected, setSelected] = useState("all")

    const getAllCategories = async() => {
        try{
            const {data} = await axios.get("http://localhost:5000/api/category")
            console.log(data)
            if(data.success){
                setCategories(data?.categories)
            }
        } catch(error){
            console.log(error)
        }
    }

  

    console.log(categories)
    console.log(selected)

    const handleRadioChange = (e) => {
        console.log(e.target.value)
        setSelected(e.target.value)
        getProductByCategory()
    }

    const getProductByCategory = async() => {
        try{
            console.log(selected)
            if(selected === "all"){
                const {data} = await axios.get("http://localhost:5000/api/product")
                console.log(data.products)
                setProducts(data.products)
            } else{
                const {data} = await axios.get(`http://localhost:5000/api/product/${selected}`)
                console.log(data.products)
                setProducts(data.products)
            }
        } catch(error){
            console.log(error)
        }
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        getAllCategories()
        // getProductByCategory()
    }, [])

    return (
        <>
            <Header />
            <main style={{ minHeight: "80vh" }}>
                <img src="/banner.png" width={"100%"} className="object-cover h-80" />
                <div className="flex justify-between gap-10 my-9">
                    <div className="basis-1/6 ms-52 flex flex-col items-start border-2 ps-4 py-4">
                        <h1 className="text-center text-2xl pb-3">Browse By Category</h1>
                        <div className="flex flex-col">
                            <div className="radio-options">
                                <div className="flex gap-3">
                                    <input type="radio" id="all" name="category" value="all" onClick={handleRadioChange} checked={selected === "all"} />
                                    <label htmlFor="category">All</label>
                                </div>
                                {categories?.map((category) => (
                                    <div className="flex gap-3">
                                        <input type="radio" id={category._id} name="category" value={category.slug} onClick={handleRadioChange} checked={selected === category.slug} />
                                        <label htmlFor="category">{category.name}</label>
                                    </div>
                                ))}
                            </div> 
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div className="basis-5/6 mt-4">
                        {/* <h1 className="text-2xl">
                            {selected === "All" ? "List of Products" : "Category: " + selected.id}
                        </h1> */}
                        <div className="flex gap-6 flex-wrap">
                            {products && products.map((product) => (
                                <div className="product-card w-[300px] h-[450px] border-[1px] border-black">
                                    <img src={`http://localhost:5000/api/product/photo/${product._id}`} className="object-cover h-[360px] w-[300px]" alt="" />
                                    <div className="product-info text-center">
                                        <h1 className="py-2">{product.name}</h1>
                                        <h5 className="text-gray-500 text-sm">Category: {product.category.name}</h5>
                                    </div>
                                    
                                </div>
                            ))}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </main>
        </>
       
    )
}
```

**controllers/product.js**

```
export const getAllProducts = async(req,res) => {
    try{
        const products = await Product.find({}).populate("category")
        res.status(201).json({success: true, products})
    } catch(err){
        console.log(err)
        res.status(404).json({
            success: false,
            message: "Error in fetching products",
            err
        })
    }
}


export const getProductByCategory = async(req,res) => {
    try{
        // const categoryId = req.params.cid
        const category = await Category.find({ slug: req.params.pslug })
        const products = await Product.find({ category: category }).select("-photo")
        res.status(201).json({success: true, products})
    } catch(err){
        console.log(err)
        res.status(404).json({
            success: false,
            message: "Error in fetching products",
            err
        })
    }
}
```

The project is not getting the value of first click in radio button instead only getting the previous click. I may want to fetch the products by category options with radio buttons and display on the page but the network only recognizing the last click so can anyone figure out how to have the project recognize the first click instead of previous click?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The useState set method is not reflecting a change immediately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54069253/the-usestate-set-method-is-not-reflecting-a-change-immediately)

Comment: Hey, actually in we don't know your backend structure. Please create codesandbox with JSON of your data, so we can look into the issue.

Comment: What should I provide in order to figure out the problem?

Comment: You don't have to maintain a state for selected radio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to maintain a state for selected `radio` button.
Just use `defaultChecked` prop for `all` value initially and use `onchange` instead of `onClick` it is best practice.

So in `onchange` event you can get the value of category then just pass it to `getProductByCategory` function thats all

```
const Homepage = () => {
    const [categories, setCategories] = useState([])
    const [products, setProducts] = useState([])
    // const [selected, setSelected] = useState("all")

    const getAllCategories = async() => {
        try{
            const {data} = await axios.get("http://localhost:5000/api/category")
            console.log(data)
            if(data.success){
                setCategories(data?.categories)
            }
        } catch(error){
            console.log(error)
        }
    }

  

    console.log(categories)
    console.log(selected)

    const handleRadioChange = (e) => {
        console.log(e.target.value)
        // setSelected(e.target.value)
        getProductByCategory(e.target.value)
    }

    const getProductByCategory = async (selected) => {
        try{
            console.log(selected)
            if(selected === "all"){
                const {data} = await axios.get("http://localhost:5000/api/product")
                console.log(data.products)
                setProducts(data.products)
            } else{
                const {data} = await axios.get(`http://localhost:5000/api/product/${selected}`)
                console.log(data.products)
                setProducts(data.products)
            }
        } catch(error){
            console.log(error)
        }
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        getAllCategories()
        // getProductByCategory()
    }, [])

    return (
        <>
            <Header />
            <main style={{ minHeight: "80vh" }}>
                <img src="/banner.png" width={"100%"} className="object-cover h-80" />
                <div className="flex justify-between gap-10 my-9">
                    <div className="basis-1/6 ms-52 flex flex-col items-start border-2 ps-4 py-4">
                        <h1 className="text-center text-2xl pb-3">Browse By Category</h1>
                        <div className="flex flex-col">
                            <div className="radio-options">
                                <div className="flex gap-3">
                                    <input type="radio" id="all" name="category" value="all" onChange={handleRadioChange} defaultChecked />
                                    <label htmlFor="category">All</label>
                                </div>
                                {categories?.map((category) => (
                                    <div className="flex gap-3">
                                        <input type="radio" id={category._id} name="category" value={category.slug} onChange={handleRadioChange} />
                                        <label htmlFor="category">{category.name}</label>
                                    </div>
                                ))}
                            </div> 
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div className="basis-5/6 mt-4">
                        {/* <h1 className="text-2xl">
                            {selected === "All" ? "List of Products" : "Category: " + selected.id}
                        </h1> */}
                        <div className="flex gap-6 flex-wrap">
                            {products && products.map((product) => (
                                <div className="product-card w-[300px] h-[450px] border-[1px] border-black">
                                    <img src={`http://localhost:5000/api/product/photo/${product._id}`} className="object-cover h-[360px] w-[300px]" alt="" />
                                    <div className="product-info text-center">
                                        <h1 className="py-2">{product.name}</h1>
                                        <h5 className="text-gray-500 text-sm">Category: {product.category.name}</h5>
                                    </div>
                                    
                                </div>
                            ))}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </main>
        </>
       
    )
}
```

Comment: Instead now I have to click two times the button checked so how to have the button clicked once already checked?